# Storing form fields in a Session and sending data as an email

Tags: php, forms, session

I previously created a script to store form fields in a session array and send them in an email. I've now tried to copy the code to a smaller two page form and it just won't work. I'm not sure what I'm missing. 
Session Start and form code for page one.

```
 <?php
 //let's start the session
 session_start();

//now, let's register our session variables
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION['all_quote_details'][$k]=$v;
}
foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $k => $v){ $result .="".      $k.", ".$v."\n"; } 

 ?> 
 <form class="number-plate-form" action="/quote2/" method="post">
<div class="bit-2">
<div class="blue-fade">
<input id="reg"  placeholder="ENTER REG"  required=""  name="reg">     </div></div><div class="bit-2"> <input value="Quote" id="quote-button"   class="btn-block-m btn-lg btn-success pulse" type="submit"></div>
 </form>
```

code for page 2

```
 <?php
//let's start the session
session_start();

//now, let's register our session variables
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION['all_quote_details'][$k]=$v;
}

?> 
<form action="/post.php" method="post">
<div class="bit-2">

<h2 class="ac">Vehicle Details</h2>
<input id="make" class="niceField" type="text" placeholder="Enter your  vehicle make" name="make" required="">
```

```
              <h2 class="ac">Your Details</h2>
 <input id="Name" class="niceField" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required >
      <input id="Email" class="niceField" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address"  name="Email" required>
      <input id="Tel" class="niceField" type="tel" placeholder="Enter your contact number" name="Tel" required>
```

```
      <br class="cb" />

   <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" id="send"> 
   <?php foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $k => $v){ $result .="". $k.", ".$v."\n"; }


   ?>
```

Email Form Code

```
 <?php
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $k => $v){ 
    $result .="". $k.",  ".$v."\n"; 
}

$to      = 'dan@dentalseoltd.co.uk';
$subject = 'TESTING ';
$message = "<td>Please See Quote   $result;</td>";


  $success =  mail($to, $subject, $message,$body, $headers); 

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}

?>
```

When the email comes through i just get the first reg form input from page one. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `$_SESSION['all_quote_details'][$k]=$v;` Did you do `$_SESSION['all_quote_details']=array()` first?

Comment: @developerwjk hi thanks for the reply, no where would i put that? Im  a newbie so struggle a little with the coding.

Comment: UPDATE* I can get the form to work correctly if i add another page into the equation. Why will it not work with only two ages but will be fine with 3?